# How to sync profile pictures with Facebook after May 2015

Tags: contacts, facebook

I just bought a new phone (OnePlus Two) and I can't get the Facebook profile sync to work. After reading up on it, it seems facebook has killed all 3rd party apps that do this back in May... which is fine, except I can't do it even with the official Facebook app... there seems to be no such option!

Yes, I added the facebook account to account; no, I have not enabled sync in facebook settings since there is no such option in the latest facebook app.

Any thoughts on how could I achieve this?